# Group contiguous symbols or words in sentence

Tags: python, split

Given a phrase containing words and symbols, I need to split the various words from the various symbols.

phrase = '$water.'

split_phrase = phrase.split(//insert your code here)
print(split_phrase)

> > ['$', 'water', '.']

Comment: Perhaps try to make your question a little more clear. Do you want to split the phrase according to certain symbols?

Comment: please make sentences and add an example of what you already tried

Answer (score 0):

```
[^\w]+ # group non characters
|      # or 
[\w]+  # or group characters
```